# lwjgl (OpenGL) incorrect Camera rotation

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, trigonometry

My Camera class has the following methods:

```
public void strafeLeft(float speed){
        cameraPosition = Vector3f.add(cameraPosition, 
                new Vector3f(-cameraRight.x * speed, 
                        -cameraRight.y * speed, 
                        -cameraRight.z * speed), 
                        null);
        lookAt(cameraPosition, Vector3f.add(cameraPosition, cameraDirection, null), up);
    }

    public void strafeRight(float speed){
        cameraPosition = Vector3f.add(cameraPosition, 
                new Vector3f(cameraRight.x * speed, 
                        cameraRight.y * speed, 
                        cameraRight.z * speed), 
                        null);
        lookAt(cameraPosition, Vector3f.add(cameraPosition, cameraDirection, null), up);
    }

    public void moveForwards(float speed){
        cameraPosition = Vector3f.add(cameraPosition, 
                new Vector3f(cameraDirection.x * speed, 
                        cameraDirection.y * speed, 
                        cameraDirection.z * speed), 
                        null);
        lookAt(cameraPosition, Vector3f.add(cameraPosition, cameraDirection, null), up);
    }

    public void moveBackwards(float speed){
        cameraPosition = Vector3f.add(cameraPosition, 
                new Vector3f(-cameraDirection.x * speed, 
                        -cameraDirection.y * speed, 
                        -cameraDirection.z * speed), 
                        null);
        lookAt(cameraPosition, Vector3f.add(cameraPosition, cameraDirection, null), up);
    }

    public void rotateCamera(int deltaX, int deltaY){
        cameraVerticalAngle -= deltaY * cameraSensitivity;
        cameraHorizontalAngle += deltaX * cameraSensitivity;

        cameraDirection.x = (float)(Math.cos(cameraVerticalAngle) * Math.sin(cameraHorizontalAngle));
        cameraDirection.y = (float)(Math.sin(cameraVerticalAngle));
        cameraDirection.z = (float)(Math.cos(cameraVerticalAngle) * Math.cos(cameraHorizontalAngle));

        cameraRight.x = (float)(Math.sin(cameraHorizontalAngle - 3.14f/2.0f));
        cameraRight.y = (float)(Math.sin(cameraVerticalAngle));
        cameraRight.z = (float)(Math.cos(cameraHorizontalAngle - 3.14f/2.0f));

        up = Vector3f.cross(cameraRight, cameraDirection, null);

        lookAt(cameraPosition, Vector3f.add(cameraPosition, cameraDirection, null), up);
    }
```

Using a test client, I was getting very weird behavior, which is easier to explain with an image. A cube is rendered to the screen and the camera can be moved around and rotated with WASD and the mouse.

[image: I apologize for the crummy paint job here.]

The problem is that when the camera is turned to the right it appears as if either the camera position is moved or the model position has moved!

I have no idea why this happening. I am using an identity matrix for the model matrix, so I'm guessing it is a problem with my view matrix, but I have no idea why... Is there something wrong with rotateCamera?

EDIT: Here is lookAt. I have since take out the parameters in lookAt since cameraPosition, cameraDirection, and up are all class variables.

```
public void lookAt() {
        Vector3f f = normalize(cameraDirection); 
        Vector3f s = normalize(cameraRight); 
        Vector3f u = normalize(up); 

        Matrix4f result = new Matrix4f();

        result.m00 = s.x;
        result.m10 = s.y;
        result.m20 = s.z;
        result.m01 = u.x;
        result.m11 = u.y;
        result.m21 = u.z;
        result.m02 = -f.x;
        result.m12 = -f.y;
        result.m22 = -f.z;


        viewMatrix = Matrix4f.translate(new Vector3f(-cameraPosition.x, -cameraPosition.y, -cameraPosition.z),  result, null);
    }
```

Comment: What does you `lookAt` method do?

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have added the code to lookAt to the post.

Comment: Am I correct, that when you move the mouse to the right, it turns to the left, and when you turn the mouse to the left, it turns to the right?

Comment: No that is not happening, the controls are not inverted. Did you notice something weird in my code?

Comment: You need to multiply `cameraPosition` with`cameraDirection` and not add them together.